# Amazon SQS - FIFO Queue message request, inconsistent receives

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a FIFO SQS queue, with visibility time of 30 seconds.
The requirement is to read messages as Quickly as possible and clear the queue.

I have code in JAVA in a fashion shown below ( *this is just a representation of idea only, not complete code* ):

```
//keep getting messages from FIFO and process them ASAP
while(true)
{
     List<Message> messages = 
     sqsclient.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
    //my logic/code here to process these messages and delete them ASAP
}
```

In the while loop as soon as the messages are received, they are processed and removed from the queue.
But, **many times** the receiveMessageRequest does not give me messages (returns zero messages).

Also, the messages limitation is only 10 at a time during receive from SQS, which is already an issue, but due to these zero receives, the queues are piling up.

I have no clue why this is happening. The documentation exactly is not clear on this part (or Am I missing in terms of the configuration of the queue?)

Please help!

**Note: 
1. My FIFO Queue always has messages in this scenario, so there is no case of Queue having zero messages and receive request returning zero**

**2. The processing and delete times are also Less than the visibility timeout.**

Thanks.

**Update:**
**I have started running multiple consumers for processing the FIFO queue. Clearly, one consumer is not coping up with the inflow of messages. I shall update in few days how multiple consumers are performing. Thanks**

Comment: Have you considered using multiple threads/clients to consume messages in parallel? Might you be hitting the limit of 300 transactions per second (TPS) for FIFO queues? Have you considered using **Long Polling** (Receive Message Wait Time), which will only return a zero-message response after a designated time period (eg 20 seconds)?

Comment: @John Thanks for replying.
Yes. I have tried long polling, similar behavior. It does not always get me messages even if the queue has more than 5000 messages.

I am attempting multiple consumers right now. But I wanted to in general understand the behavior

Comment: How many messages are currently showing as **in flight**?  A FIFO queue requires that you handle each message correctly, and if you don't, they'll show up "in flight" and -- by design -- SQS waits for you to act on them or for their visibility timeout to expire.  Check this?

Comment: Hi Michael, the In-Flight are almost always zero, that means they are getting processed and deleted.

Answer (score 3):

You have to first make sure that all messages you received are deleted within VisibilityTimeout. If you are using [DeleteMessageBatch](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteMessageBatch.html) for deletion make sure that all 10 messages are deleted.

Also, how did you queue messages when you enqueue them?
Order of messages are guaranteed only in a single message group.
This also means that if you set the same group id to all messages, you are limited to a single consumer so that order of messages are preserved for sure. Even if use multiple consumers, all messages that belong to a same group becomes invisible to other consumers until visibility timeout expires.

Comment: What are "other" consumers...same SQS Client in loop is considered a single consumer or multiple different ones for each iteration?